# Customizing Top navbar in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am new to SharePoint and I need to add icon to the top navigation bar like profile pic of the user and notification bell with styling.

I tried with edit option but it supports only emoji and text and also with SPFx extension but I am not getting how to access top navbar.

can anyone please suggest me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

@User123

You can inject some css/JS to the modern UI through SPFx extension. Please take a reference of below demo:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/app-extension-js/src/extensions/helloWorld/HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.ts

Test result:

[image]

More reference:

- [SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss#spfx-applications-customiser-css-injection)
- https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/

BR